# Getting error you cannot render a component Exercise inside ExerciseList component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my ExerciseList component that will show all the exercises over which i can further edit or delete my list of exercises.
In return of ExerciseList i am returning Exercise Component or function. So Can anyone please check, what i am doing wrong and how to correct this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



const Exercise = (props) => {   //This is Exercise component
    <tr>
      <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.duaration}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.date}</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/" + props.exercise._id}>edit</Link> |
        <a href="#" onClick={props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id)}>
          delete
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const ExerciseList = () => {
  const [exerciseList, setExerciseList] = useState({
    exercises: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/exercises/")
      .then((res) => {
        setExerciseList({
          exercises: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const deleteExercise = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:5000/exercises/" + id)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    setExerciseList({
      exercises: exerciseList.exercises.filter((el) => el._id !== id),
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Logged Exercises</h3>
      <table className="table">
        <thead className="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {exerciseList.exercises.map((currentExercise) => {
            return (
              <Exercise
                exercise={currentExercise}
                deleteExercise={deleteExercise}
                key={currentExercise._id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default ExerciseList;

Comment: Your `Exercise` component doesn't **_return_** anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Exercise component is missing the return statement, should be like this:

```
const Exercise = (props) => {  
return (
 <tr>
      <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.duaration}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.date}</td>
      <td>
        <Link to={"/edit/" + props.exercise._id}>edit</Link> |
        <a href="#" onClick={props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id)}>
          delete
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
);
};
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the solution and want to add one more thing is that inside onClick event listener it should be  "onClick={() => props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id)}"  instead of "onClick={props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id)}" because it will delete all the exercises even before we go to event listener

Comment: Yeah correct ^ didn't check that code initially